# Select box wil not select value, it will show the options but can not select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I populate a select using ng-options. In the value it gives a addon_id (from json data) and the name is addon_name. but I also have a variable called addon_priceoption (wich can be 'free' or 'paid') and if its paid i want to show addon_price ... this works with the following code:

```
  <div ng-show="group.group_optiontype == 'single'">
    <select ng-model="foo1" ng-options="singleAddon.addon_name as formattedLabel(singleAddon) for singleAddon in group.addons track by singleAddon.addon_id" name="addon-single" class="form-control-wrapper col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
       <option value="" ng-hide="foo1">Choose please </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

// in the controller

```
$scope.formattedLabel = function(singleAddon){
  if(singleAddon.addon_priceoption =='paid'){
   return singleAddon.addon_name + ' (+ €' + singleAddon.addon_price +' )';
  }else{
   return singleAddon.addon_name;
  }
};
```

I get a select box with all the options. Also it shows a price if a select has a price. But for some reason now I can not select a option. I can click it but it does not change it stays at the default value.

when i do:

```
singleAddon.addon_name for singleAddon in group.addons track by singleAddon.addon_id
```

in the NG options, i can select the options.. but with the price modification i can not select?

Why is this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your code

```
<select ng-model="foo1" ng-options="singleAddon.addon_name as formattedLabel(singleAddon) for singleAddon in group.addons track by singleAddon.addon_id" name="addon-single" class="form-control-wrapper col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
       <option value="" ng-hide="foo1">Choose please </option>
    </select>
```

You are doing "ng-options='singleAddon.addon_name'"  and you are already returning the name, not the object itself, in your formattedLabel function.